# Need example of how to create/manipulate image pixel data with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, image

Looking for a simple example or link to a tutorial.

Say I have a bunch of values stored in an array.  I would like to create an image and update the image data from my array.  Assume the array values are intensity data and will be updating a grayscale image.  Assume the array values are between 0 and 255 -- or that I will convert it to that range.

This is not for purposes of animation.  Rather the image would be updated based on user interaction.  This is something I know how to do well in Java, but am very new to iPhone programming.  I've googled some information about CGImage and UIImage -- but am confused as to where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can start by looking at CGContext and CGBitmapContext, but I do not know any good examples off hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have sample code from one of my apps that takes data stored as an array of unsigned char and turns it into a UIImage:

```
// unsigned char *bitmap; // This is the bitmap data you already have.
// int width, height; // bitmap length should equal width * height

// Create a bitmap context with the image data
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmap, width, height, 8, width, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
CGImageRef cgImage = nil;
if (context != nil) {
    cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

// Release the cgImage when done
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your colorspace is RGB and you need to account alpha value pass `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` as last parameter to `CGBitmapContextCreate` function.

Don't use `kCGImageAlphaLast`, this will not work because bitmap contexts do not support alpha that isn't premultiplied.

Answer (score 0):

The books I referenced in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718262/how-did-you-get-into-objective-c/2718275#2718275) both contain sample code and demonstrations of image manipulations and updates via user interaction.